# Why does my code execute IF block even if dates comparison fail?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

Expiry Date = '2017-10-16' and ExpiryTime='12:00pm' in table and in our country Getdate is '2017-10-16' and currentdatetime is '2017-10-16 11:05:33.503'

but still, my code executes the IF condition which it should not. Why ?

```
        Declare @ExpiryDate date
        Declare @ExpiryTime varchar(10)

        Set @ExpiryDate= (Select convert(varchar(11), ExpiryDate, 106) from Works where NIT_No= @NITNo and WorkNo= @WorkNo)
        Set @ExpiryTime= (Select CAST(ExpiryTime as TIME(0)) from Works where NIT_No= @NITNo and WorkNo= @WorkNo)

        IF(CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ExpiryDate,106)+ ' ' + @ExpiryTime) <= CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE()))   
        Begin
            RAISERROR('Sorry, Expiry date and time has passed', 16, 10);
            return;
        End
```

Comment: Why are you using conversion code `106` and also why are doing so many conversions between varchar and date?

Comment: I'm confused about `12:00pm`...I can't tell if that's 2017-10-16 morning (0:00) or 2017-10-17 0:00...in the first case, your `IF` _is_ `true`.

Comment: That is why you do not use strings to manipulate dates!

Answer (score 2):

12:00pm is translated to 00:00 in 24 hour format. If you combine the current date and 12:00pm, you expect the result to be midnight of the next day, but actually you get midnight of the current day.

That should work:

```
    Declare @ExpiryDate date
    Declare @ExpiryTime varchar(10)

    Set @ExpiryDate= (Select convert(varchar(11), ExpiryDate, 106) from Works where NIT_No= @NITNo and WorkNo= @WorkNo)
    Set @ExpiryTime= (Select CAST(ExpiryTime as TIME(0)) from Works where NIT_No= @NITNo and WorkNo= @WorkNo)

    declare @dateTimeCombined datetime = dateadd(ms, datediff(ms, '00:00:00', @ExpiryTime), cast(@ExpiryDate as datetime))

    IF @dateTimeCombined <= CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE())
    Begin
        RAISERROR('Sorry, Expiry date and time has passed', 16, 10);
        return;
    End
```